# Sending an event from my REST webapi server to a specific client in c#

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-web-api

So I have a .NET project and my goal is to send an event to a specific user from the server. This event of course will have all kind of information, the ideal way would be for it to be similar to the REST requests from client/server... But I can't think my way through it. I've heard terms like sockets and stuff and someone told me that I could do it with a system similar to message system but can't find anything about it. [Here is a conceptual example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qR6o0.png)

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend you checking out `SignalR` which is a protocol-wrapper over port 80 (the one browsers and web traffic uses). This way you can have the server send stuff to the client whenever the server wants. The more basic approach is to let the client poll the client (send a `GET`/`POST`-request) in intervals (~once a second) and return your information in the poll request response.